# Как разделить Telegram кнопки (команды) и вводимый текст?

Tags: php, json, telegram-bot

Создал бота Telegram, который по нажатию на кнопки выводит заданные результате по командам:
/help
/test и т.д.

Но кроме кнопок, у меня есть возможность отправить запрос для поиска на моем сервере и получения результатов.

Появилась проблема, могу выводить только что-то одно, либо бот работает со значениями прописанными для кнопок, либо работает только с поисковыми запросами, иначе получается, что по нажатию на кнопку 
/help происходит не заданное выполнение команды на кнопке, а поиск /help на сервере.

Не знаю, смог ли донести мысль и проблему...

**Вопрос, можно ли как-то разделить команды на кнопках и текстовые команды вводимые вручную?**

```
if($text){
     if ($text == "/start") {

        $reply = $name.", спасибо, что запустили меня! ";

        $telegram = API_URL . "sendMessage?chat_id=" . $chat_id . "&reply_markup=" . $keyboard . "&text=" . urlencode($reply);

    }elseif ($text == "/help") {

        $reply = "Информация с помощью.";

        $telegram = API_URL . "sendmessage?chat_id=" . $chat_id . "&text=" . $reply;

    }elseif ($response) {

foreach($response as $key=>$item){
// $response поисковый запрос
// код выводящий результаты поиска на сервере
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил перестроением кода. У меня после кода для поиска вручную

```
}elseif ($response) {

foreach($response as $key=>$item){
```

шли другие команды типа

```
 if ($text == "/start") {

    $reply = $name.", спасибо, что запустили меня! ";

    $telegram = API_URL . "sendMessage?chat_id=" . $chat_id . "&reply_markup=" . $keyboard . "&text=" . urlencode($reply);

}elseif ($text == "/help") {

    $reply = "Информация с помощью.";

    $telegram = API_URL . "sendmessage?chat_id=" . $chat_id . "&text=" . $reply;

}
```

Перенес все команды выполняемые по нажатию на кнопки вверх кода, код для ручного поиска поставил последним, проблема решилась.